# HTTP response looks different in Chrome browse and angular2 code

Tags: angular, http

I do a simple POST:

```
this.http.post(<config>)
    .subscribe((response) => {
console.log(response)})
```

In Chrome Browser Network tab I see it as a binary.
In console I see it as a JSON.
So what is the real response type? Binary or JSON. I cannot save that binary then. Is there something I need to add to the request body? Regardless of what is my post request, why it look different in Chrome?

Comment: The real response type can be learnt from the server which is sending it, and the content type header tell us what type of response it is. Most of the times it is JSON. You can use the response object as is, and can work out something like "response.status" or "response.data"

Comment: OK.. in Chrome console it says:

message: "Http failure during parsing for https://xxxxxx.xxx/submitMyRequest

"name:"HttpErrorResponse"

But why it look binary in Chrome Network/response tab?

Comment: If you could paste some screenshots that would be great. Also, over the wire, and over the net, the content is HTTP. But every medium that is set up to handle it - say a browser - can interpret into a common format, for e.g. JSON. That is difference between the n/w tab (former) and the browser console (latter).

Comment: Hv u set headers like content-type: application/json ?

Comment: OK.. now I set content type in request body and and option. Now it outputs binary in both, console and Network tab...

"options": { responseType: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'}

Answer (score 0):

To have it all simple and get the response body proper, here is a sample implementation of a post request ->

```js
constructor(private _http: Http) {
        this.handleError = this.handleError.bind(this);
    }

    public PostData(data: any): Observable<any> {


                //Check if you need access tokens. Usually posts need access tokens. 
                 let access_token: string = "";

                let url: string = "https://YourPostDataUrl/PostdataEndPoint";
                let headers = new Headers({
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token,
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                });

                let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

                return this._http.post(url, data, options)
                    .map(res => res.json())
                    .catch(this.handleError)

    }
```

To access this method here is a sample method -

```js
saveEvent(): void{

  this._serviceProvider.PostData(this.data)
  .subscribe(data => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    //Show Some Message. Say pop a dialog/modal confirming the data save.
  })
```

Also, to your response on Chrome console - as mentioned in the comment - over the wire, and over the net, the content is HTTP. But every medium that is set up to handle it - say a browser - can interpret into a common format, for e.g. JSON. That is difference between the n/w tab (former) and the browser console (latter).

********Updated to respond to the unbound callback comment**************'
What the comment refers to is that event handler callbacks are usually invoked as functions, not as methods. This means that the this expressions of such callbacks evaluate to undefined or the global object. Using an ES6 class method as a callback therefore means that the this expressions of the method do not refer to the class instance.

Updated the code with a reference to the constructor where the callback event handler is explicitly bound to *this*.

Comment: Don't pass unbound callbacks.

Comment: Update the answer, please.

Comment: Why don't you? You'll be glad you did when you understand why

Comment: Updated the answer.